# Cyclic subgroups of semidirect products

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, semidirect-product

Let $H$ and $N$ be two finite groups and $\phi:H\to Aut(N)$ a homomorphism.
Let $G=N\rtimes_\phi H$ and let $\pi:G\to G/N=H$ be the quotient map.

Let $p$ be a prime which does not divide $|N|$ but does divide $|H|$, and let $\gamma:C_p\to G$ be a homomorphism.
($C_p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$.)
If $\gamma$ is nontrivial, $\gamma(C_p)$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$, and I would like to understand such subgroups better.

Do we have $\gamma(C_p)\subset\{e_N\}\times H<G$, perhaps under some additional assumptions?
That is, does the homomorphism $\gamma$ have to be trivial on $N$, so to say?

I know that the claim is true if $\phi|_{\pi(\gamma(C_p))}$ is trivial (which happens if, for example, $p$ does not divide $|\phi(H)|$), but I would prefer not to make assumptions on the homomorphism $\phi$ and $\gamma$ (especially $\gamma$).
Assumptions on the groups $H$ and $N$ would be more convenient.

**Edit:**
Since $|\phi(H)|$ divides $|H|$, it does indeed happen for some primes $p$ satisfying the division requirements that $p$ divides $|\phi(H)|$.

**Refined question:**
Let $H,N,\phi$ be as above.
As a set, we can write $G=N\times H$.
Are there any assumptions on the groups $H$ and $N$ so that for every prime $p$ dividing $|H|$ but not $|N|$ the following is true:
If $(n,h)\in N\times H=G$ has order $p$, then $n=e_N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be an odd number and $$G=D_{2n}=\langle x,y|x^n=y^2=1,yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}\rangle,$$ with $N=\langle x\rangle\cong \Bbb Z/n$ and $H=\langle y\rangle\cong \Bbb Z/2$.

Now $yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}=x^{n-1}$ implies $x^{-1}yx=x^{n-2}y$. That means $x^{n-2}y$ has order $2$ and of course $x^{n-2}\neq 1$.

**Edit**: I just realize that I didn't really answer the question. However, I think the example above represents somewhat the general idea.

One only needs to consider the case $H=\langle h\rangle\cong\Bbb Z/p$. Since $p$ does not divide $|N|$, $\langle h\rangle$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. The condition
$$(nh)^p=1$$ then implies that $\langle nh\rangle$ is conjugate to $\langle h\rangle$ by $g\in N$. In particular
$$nh=g^{-1}h^kg,$$
or 
$$gnhg^{-1}=h^{k}.$$
Equivalently one has $h^{k-1}\in N\cap \langle h\rangle=1$, or
$$nh=g^{-1}hg.$$
Here, in general $n\ne1$ unless $H=\langle h\rangle$ is also normal in $NH$, which is equivalent to the trivial action of $h$ on $N$.

Comment: We now know that generally $n$ is a commutator of $h\in H$ and $g\in N$ and that this commutator can be nontrivial in the dihedral groups. I have a faint feeling that this has something to do with $C_2$ being even ($D_{2n}=C_n\rtimes C_2$). Are there concrete examples where $|N|$ and $|H|$ are odd?

Comment: I don't think so as I didn't use the fact that $y^2=1$. Another example is the wreath product $N^p\times \Bbb Z/p$, where $\Bbb Z/p$ acts by cycling the components.

Comment: Thanks. That example gives me a clearer image of the situation. (I'll wait until the end of the bounty period before accepting an answer in case someone has something to add.)

Answer (score 0):

The element $n$ is not necessarily trivial, as the other answer points out.

Suppose that $nh$ has order $p$. Then $1=(nh)^p=nhnh\cdots nh=n^{\prime}h^p$ where $n^{\prime}\in N$. As $N\cap H=1$, $n^{\prime}=1=h^p$. Hence, $h$ has order dividing $p$, but we cannot conclude this about $n$.

The element $n^{\prime}$ has the form $\phi(n)\phi^2(n)\cdots\phi^{p}(n)$, so all you can really say is that this element is trivial, which is really a description of the automorphism $\phi$.